# How to forward ip (something like ethernet) via USB from Raspberry pi?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, meta-raspberrypi

I am looking to use Raspberry Pi 3' 4 USB ports to forward ip address, such that the devices connected to these USB ports feel as if Raspberry Pi is a router.

The way these devices(or sensors) work is, they setup a socket server on their ip address and I am looking to connect to these sockets through python program in RPi to receive the data they capture and stream through socket connection. There can be 3 or 4 devices connected to Raspberry Pi. Also, these devices have an ethernet output cable to send those streams. I have successfully achieved this for 1 device connecting to ethernet cable but I am facing problem in doing the same thing via USB port.

I am looking to find some solution for the same. Do please share your suggestions. 
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "forward ip address". Do you mean forward all data to/from an IP address?

Comment: @boardrider: No. I mean to use the raspberry pi  as a router but only for usb and ethernet ports but not wifi.